# How can I reorder a list in LAMBDA?

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to show the highest values first, but its showing me the lower first:

```
songs.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
     .forEach(songs -> System.out.println(songs.getKey() + " Rate:" + songs.getValue()));
```

Comment: I think there's a `Comparator.reverse` that will reverse the sense of your test, and the order of the sorting.

Comment: How are you comparing them? I mean, if you don't give it anything, it'll use the default...

Comment: Also note that there is `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` (instead of `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)`).